# Dafny can't verify multiple iterators in while loop

Tags: dafny

I want to have a function that allocates two iterators, and then goes into a loop that repeatedly calls MoveNext() on the iterators for as long as MoveNext() returns true. However, calling MoveNext() on what iterator violates (or prevents Dafny from verifying) the invariant necessary for the other iterator:

```
iterator Iter1()
{ yield; }

iterator Iter2()
{ yield; }

method main()
    decreases *
{
    var iter1 := new Iter1();
    var iter2 := new Iter2();
    var iter1More := true;
    var iter2More := true;

    while (iter1More || iter2More)
        invariant iter1More ==> iter1.Valid() && fresh(iter1._new)
        // The following invariant is not verified
        invariant iter2More ==> iter2.Valid() && fresh(iter2._new)
        decreases *
    {
        if (iter1More) {
            iter1More := iter1.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

Dafny cannot verify `iter2More ==> iter2.Valid() && fresh(iter2._new)`, even though Iter1 has an empty modifies clause. Is there a loop invariant I need to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this one was fun :)

Here's the additional invariant you need to verify it

```
invariant {iter1} + iter1._new !! {iter2} + iter2._new
```

This invariant is also sufficient to prove a more complex loop that calls both iterators, like this:

```
    if (iterMore1) {
        iterMore1 := iter1.MoveNext();
    }
    if (iterMore2) {
        iterMore2 := iter2.MoveNext();
    }
```

The way I figured this out was that Dafny was complaining that `iter2.Valid()` might not hold after the call to `iter1.MoveNext()`. Any time a predicate that was true before a call might not be true after the call, you know the problem is that Dafny could not prove the reads clause of the function did not overlap with the modifies clause of the method. Unfortunately, neither the reads clause of an iterator's `Valid()` predicate, nor the modifies clause of an iterator's `MoveNext()` method are documented. I dove into the Boogie output of Dafny and was able to reverse engineer them as follows

```
predicate Valid()
  reads this, this._reads, this._new

method MoveNext()
  modifies this, this._modifies, old(this._new)
```

I was also able to see that Dafny can show that both `Iter1` and `Iter2` have empty `_reads` and `_modifies` sets. So really it's just the references themselves, and their `_new` sets. This explains the invariant.

Comment: Impressive sleuthing, @James Wilcox! Though `iterator` documentation leaves something to be desired, there is an easier way to discover the information you reverse engineered from the Boogie code: Dafny's `/rprint` switch (which you can use the with argument `-` to print to standard out, as in `/rprint:-`) prints out the iterator's generated members.